# Page Navigation In UWP

Tags: uwp

I'm creating a solution in order to run on a raspberry pi2 with Windows IOT, Created a button, and I was wondering if there was a way to show a second XAML page I created, by a button event such as Button_Click, in the said frame.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Yes there is. I advise you to start reading about how the navigation system (including history stack for the back button) works in UWP because this will save a lot frustration onward. The MSDN tutorial for example will guide you to a few possibilities for how to navigate.

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer the question, you can use `Frame.Navigate(typeof(<YourPage>))`. I'd suggest reading some articles such as [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2e414e/basic-navigation-between-pages-using-xaml-C-Sharp-in-windows-st/), for more info.

Comment: The C# Corner article does not explain caching, right? I think the equivalent MSDN article is [Quickstart: Navigating between pages (XAML) (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx) and it does mention caching. It is interesting that Microsoft's [Navigation basics for UWP apps - UWP app developer | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/navigation-basics)  does not explain any of that.